# Infuse array of array of objects into just an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

So I have the following function inside my js file:

```
function get_array_of_post_objects(slug)
{
    let items = [];
    wp.api.loadPromise.done(function () {
        const Posts = wp.api.collections.Posts.extend({
            url: wpApiSettings.root + 'menus/v1/locations/' + slug,
        });
        const all_posts = new Posts();
        all_posts.fetch().then((posts) => {
            console.log(posts.items);
            items.push(posts.items);
        });
    });
    console.log(items);
    return items;
}
```

Inside the `all_posts.fetch` call, I have a `console.log(posts.items)` which outputs the following array of objects which is perfect:
[image]

---

**The Problem**:
In my return, I have a `return items` which is what I want to return the items, but it's returning them as an array of array of objects which is not what I want as shown below:
[image]

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I ultimately want my return to just return an array of objects and not an array of array of objects - All help is appreciated.

Comment: instead of `items.push(posts.items)` try `items = posts.items`. I think `posts.items` is an array of objects and you're pushing into `items` (which is an array) an array of objects.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @AHMEDSAJJAD, I tried that but then my `return items` is getting back an empty array, so I was wondering what it could have been.

Comment: use the spread operator, `items.push(...posts.items)`. This will push into the `items` array each item in the `posts.items` array.

Comment: Hey @AHMEDSAJJAD, the `items.push(...posts.items)` worked perfectly! Please post it as the final answer - I will have to do more research into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that you were pushing into the `items` array an array of objects `posts.items`. By using the `spread` operator `...` you can push each item of the `posts.items` array into `items`.

```
...
all_posts.fetch().then((posts) => {
    console.log(posts.items);
    items.push(...posts.items);
});
...
```

You can read more about the `spread` operator here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are pushing posts.items (which is already an array of objects), into items (which is initialised as an empty array).

Do you need to have an array holding posts.items?
Instead you could simply just say `items = posts.items` since posts.items is already an array of objects, which is what you say you require.

```
function get_array_of_post_objects(slug)
{
    let items;
    wp.api.loadPromise.done(function () {
        const Posts = wp.api.collections.Posts.extend({
            url: wpApiSettings.root + 'menus/v1/locations/' + slug,
        });
        const all_posts = new Posts();
        all_posts.fetch().then((posts) => {
            console.log(posts.items);
            items = posts.items;
        });
    });
    console.log(items);
    return items;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Tom, I tried this method but now my `return items` is not picking up the `let items;` and it's coming back as undefined.

Comment: I used the `items.push(...posts.items)` method as described here and it seemed to have worked, will need to do more research into it. Thanks for the contribution tho Tom!